# change button name which represent fetch row id

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Good morning developers, i had a problem. i should do one poject for my university. For this project i got fetch information from another table and each row i put button. once user click the button should change to request sent. the problem is i create simple javascript code. that code only change button for first row id and not affect other id. another thing is, the insert php function also work for the first row id. before i apply javascript my insert function wrk properly. i hope dear developes can identify my fault.

php

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      

      $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
         $main_subject=$row["main_subject"];
         $subject_add=$row["subject_add"];
        $rate_main=$row["rate_main"];
        $rate_add=$row["rate_add"];
        $qualification=$row["qualification"];?>
        <table><form method="post">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td height="230"><img src='<?php echo $profile;?>'width="200" height="200"/>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td></td>
        <td class="data" width="800"><strong>Username:</strong>  <?php echo $username;?></br>
        <strong>Address:</strong>  <?php echo $address;?></br>
        <strong>Gender:</strong><?php echo $gender;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject:</strong><?php echo $main_subject  ;?></br>
         <strong>Subject Added: </strong><?php echo $subject_add;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject Rate:</strong> <?php echo $rate_main;?></br>
        <strong> Added Subject Rate:</strong><?php echo $rate_add; ?></br>
         <strong>Qualification:</strong> <?php echo $qualification; ?></td>
           <?php 
         if($register_ID == $_SESSION['myid']){
                ?>
                <td><label>Your Profile</label></td>
                <?php
            } else {

                    ?>
                 <form name="post">
                 <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />  
                 <input onclick="change()" type="button" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="addfriend" data-uid=<?php echo $register_ID;?>    /></td>
</form>                   
</td> 
<?php
            }
            }
?>
 </tr>
</div>
</table>
 </form>
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['id']) ) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$friend_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = 1;
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','$status','$friend_id') ";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          echo "Request Send" ;
            }
                  else {
                             $_SESSION['addfriend']="Add Friend";   }   
            }
                }
?>
```

javascript

```
function change ()
{
document.getElementById("addfriend").value="Request Sent";

}
```

Comment: This is only working for the first row because the id of the button is replicated for each iteration of the loop. You need to have a unique id for each element. Perhaps append the index count to each button and then pass that into the function  -- onclick="change(this.id)"-- when id would be "addFriend1", "addFriend2" ... etc

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach, without javascript.

Replace the addfriend input with this

```
<input type="button" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php if($has_been_added == 'yes'){ echo 'Request Sent'}else{ echo 'Addfriend'; } ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $register_ID;?>    />
```

And then in the while loop, after

```
    $qualification=$row["qualification"];
```

add

```
    $has_been_added = $row["has_been_added"];
```

Change your insert query to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,friend_id,has_been_added)" ."VALUES('$user_id','$status','$friend_id','yes')";
```

Which means you have to add has_been_added column to your friends table and give it a default value of no

This means that has_been_added will be updated to yes whenever any friend is added. Hence the corresponding button will either be Addfriend or Request Sent